# React Native: Release app not connecting to local server

Tags: android, reactjs, axios, react-native

I'm trying to build a release version of my app on android.

Followed the necessary steps from creating a signed apk through [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android). Once I install the apk on my device, the initial page loads but I get no response when I try to do an action calling the api.

I've ran my local server and have connected my app to the same IP with the server I'm running on.

The debug version of my app is doing well and I'm confused as to why this is happening. I'm using axios for the calls and have set my url to something like this: `http://192.168.12.24:8000/api/`.

Do you have ideas on what could have gone wrong? Does react native not allow using local server in a release app?

Comment: I was facing similar issue . this solution worked out for me.<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189301/axios-in-react-native-not-calling-server-in-localhost

Answer (score 4):

Adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `<application>` tag in `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` worked for me.

The reason is by default release build expects **https** url connections and it is possible that your server is having **http** based API like http://192.168.12.24:8000/api/, so to avoid this filter, usesCleartextTraffic="true" makes http based api to be accessible from release build.

you can read more about here. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24361

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix the problem. It turns out I should run the bundle every time I generate a new apk.

This is what I did:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest andro id/app/src/main/res`

`cd android`

`./gradlew assembleRelease`

Referenced from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139065/9201615).