# React Native creating Old Apk

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, frontend

I'm working on react native, but the problem is that it keeps generating old build and any changes in the code doesn't reflect on my app anymore I've tried all possible solutions but nothing works for me. Can anyone knows the solution.

react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/assets
this command produces me this error which is in picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtNha.png)

Comment: same problem. simulator has new UI. but apk-debug has old UI. apk-release has new UI. I have no idea. need help

Comment: clear cache and create new build

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give your RN version, and a little more specification on what changes you are making in your code.

I have added a reference of a similar question.
[React native is stuck at old version app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45074757/react-native-is-stuck-at-old-version-app)

Comment: Im trying to change bg color but this doesn't reflect on my app

Comment: There are many way to add bg color. You need to be more clear with your doubts.
 <View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor: '#6ED4C8'}}>
</View>. 

Reference from the docs : https://reactnative.dev/docs/style

Comment: yeah i know but any changes in my code doesn't reflect on my app so what should i do know. my code generating the old apk not the updated one.

Comment: My react native is stuck at old version of app

Comment: You will have to re-bundle your project assets but seems like you don't have permission to run the script you are trying. Change your admin permission or directly build it from xcode